# How to implement responsible container in Stack in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

So here stack with two containers. 1st container has a background image. 2nd container has text with a fixed container size. But if the screen size is different, 2nd container text does not look fine. So it should be responsible according to `1st container`. Is any way to define it like, `1st container` should have `70%` and `2nd container` should have `30%` of occupancy?

```
Stack(
      children: [
        Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
          image: DecorationImage(
            image: NetworkImage(backgroudImg),
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
        )),
        Positioned(
          left: 0,
          right: 0,
          bottom: 0,
          child: Container(
            height: 45,
            color: const Color(0xFF0E3311).withOpacity(0.5),
            child: Text(title),
          ),
        )
        ,
      ],
    )
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
  Container(
        height: "your height",
        width: "your width",
         decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular("INT 15 or 20 your choice"),
                  image: DecorationImage(
                    image: NetworkImage(backgroudImg),
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  ),
                )),
            child: Stack(
            children: [
            Align(
          child: Alignment.bottomCenter or bottom,
        child : Container(
       height: "your height",
        width: "your width",
        decoration : BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(bottomleft and bottomright)
    ),
    child: Center(
    child: Text(""))))]))
```

Comment: But the containers will not responsible, right?

Comment: if your worrying about  sizes get a package for sizes that make automatically compute. like flutter_screenutil on you container text or anything that you would like to put some sizes